# Property 'images' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to merge these two projects.

[Bearded - An iPhone photo app](https://github.com/abijlani/Bearded)

[Thumbnail Picker View](http://code4app.net/ios/Thumbnail-Picker-View/4f825cad06f6e79f79000000)

At this point I'm just trying to keep these in separate view controllers and getting the functionality of the Thumbnail Picker working in it's own controller.

I'm getting the error, as stated in the title, "Property 'images' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'"

The error is coming from the AppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:paths.count];
for (NSString *path in paths) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
}

self.viewController.images = images;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}


@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

I've tried declaring a property like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *images;
```

I can't seem to fix this even though I painstakingly merged these two codebases.

Here is the Xcode project of where I'm at at this point:

[Xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/32p5bgtxlnleshp/ElfBooth.zip)

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. I think that merging two code bases, from GitHub for example as in this case, is quite relevant for an iOS developer.

Answer (score 3):

the "`images`" property you've declared in your .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *images;
```

is not the NSMutableArray you are trying to assign to it via this line:

```
self.viewController.images = images;
```

If you can get the types to be the same (i.e. either a single UIImageView object or a NSMutableArray containing many UIImages), then you should have better luck with assigning things to that property.

Comment: Yes, however, that property line was an attempt of trying to fix the error. It's not in the original 'Thumbnail Picker View' project I linked to. I don't understand why it runs in that project and not in mine when the code is identical. The only thing I did was change: `@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;`cause I was getting an error there as well.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the names of both to avoid confusion.

Comment: You change the object of customized (inherited) ViewController with generic UIViewController . In project there should be a ViewController.m and .h that will be implemented and current file using its object... hope it helps

Comment: @K'am I did try changing this line: `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];` to this `self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: @K'am  Also, the ViewController files in this project have been renamed to ElfViewController. Since I've merged these two projects and using Storyboard, I've had to rename these controllers.

Comment: @Paul then use    `self.viewController = [[ElfViewController alloc] init];` As you are using ElfViewController's object

Comment: ElfViewController's object will have images array as instance var. Did it have??

Comment: @K'am Yes, I did that already, but thanks! It seems to have cleared the error :) I also changed this `@property (strong, nonatomic) ElfViewController *viewController;`It seems to have cleared the issue. The problem now is that I have a `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and the project still won't build. I'll post the answer here when I figure it out. Or you can post it as an answer and I'll give you the checkmark. I'm pretty sure it will solve this issue.

Comment: @K'am Yes, ElfViewController.h has `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *images;`

Comment: @K'am Yup! That was it. I finally got it to build!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that I was merging a project using Storyboards and one that was using programmatically generated ViewController. Well, part of the problem.

Since, I merged the projects I had to give the view controller with the ThumbnailView another name. I named it ElfViewController.

This is the working code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class ElfViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ElfViewController *viewController; // Changed here to ElfViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *firstViewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ElfViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ElfViewController alloc] init]; //Changed here to ElfViewController
self.firstViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:paths.count];
for (NSString *path in paths) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
}

self.viewController.images = images;
self.window.rootViewController = self.firstViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

@end
```

I'm still new to Objective-C and have only learned how to create ViewControllers in Storyboard and not programmatically.

Also I didn't know that you can declare a property to a specific View Controller rather than just a general `UIViewContoller`. That's another place I got tripped up.